# Troubleshooting a USB GPS receiver on Windows

Tags: windows-10, gps

I've got a USB GPS receiver that creates a virtual COM port in the OS. I have installed [GPSDirect](http://www.turboirc.com/gps7/) driver in order to create a Windows Location sensor out of it so that Microsoft Maps app would work. And it did work on my desktop. But now I've installed the computer and the GPS receiver into my car, and Maps never shows my location since.

So, I need to find out if it's a driver / location sensor problem, if I need to do something in Maps to make it work, or if the GPS signal is blocked by some internals of my car. Is there a program that could visualize low-level GPS data from the receiver via the Location Sensor API? If not, is there such a program that would work with a serial port GPS (if I uninstall the GPS Direct driver)?

Comment: Where is it installed "in the car".

Comment: @Ramhound: under the dashboard. Should be receiving straight through the windshield and the dashboard plastic. Or at least that's the idea.

Comment: My best suggestion see if it works if you put it on the dashboard, the reciever might not be strong enough, If it doesn't have line of sight I know my Garnin "searches for satellites" if it out it on the floor of the car

Comment: @Ramhound: I would generally start by doing that, but I need to disassemble half the car to get to the receiver. Naturally, I'm not looking forward to it. Want to have a diagnosis before I start operating, you know.

Comment: If i had built in a GPS device into a car, the recievers on the roof :-)  There are some windshields made (even) that people have found will reduce the gps signals. The glovebox while plastic may very well have metal framing , added to the metal framing of the dashboard parts and pieces.  Add to that the quality of the gps reciever and antenna, and that could be the problem. While there are many other things possible to be a problem, the hardware itself and the layers of software involved. Plus the way the reciever works, cold start, AGPS dependancy. If you suspect blockage,  so would I.

Comment: @Psycogeek: yep, I know. That's why it would be handy if I could actually see the data that the receiver is streaming. E. g. if it sees any satellites. Or if it actually does provide any data at all, for starters.

Comment: like a "GPS Status" for windows. that information should be available from any reciever pumping out data , didnt the hardware part come with any software ?

Comment: @Psycogeek: no, it did not, it implements the standard serial protocol for GPS receivers.

Comment: Prolly should have done a semi-test install, it's location, before final install :$

Comment: @Ramhound: It was done in a workshop, inside a capital building, in winter. We couldn't test there.

Comment: Yes; I realize that, just saying little duck tape goes a long way for a semi-install to test the signal location, I truly belive that's the problem though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I'd expect your GPS receiver to support [NMEA protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183). To test it, you should install a terminal emulator (e.g. [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)), connect to the COM port created by your GPS and examine the data you're receiving. You may need to remove GPSDirect before (or use a laptop for testing).

In my experience, you should start receiving something right away, before any satellites are found (like `$GPZDA` strings with current time). Once the GPS finds enough satellites to provide a usable position data, it will start sending `$GPGGA` and `$GPGLL` strings. If you never see those, it usually means the signal is too weak. `$GPGGA` strings actually have a special field (#7, according to [this document](http://freenmea.net/docs/nmea0183)) which tells you how many satellites are in view.

Comment: I actually ended up using the free VisualGPS software (http://www.visualgps.net/#visualgps-content) for that, it's convenient enough and displays all you need for troubleshooting.

Comment: Sorry for bumping the question then, I thought you were still looking for an answer.

Comment: Your answer actually does answer the question and contains some interesting technical information, there's no reason it shouldn't be accepted.